# OpenGL 3.3 (mac) Error validating program: Validation Failed: No vertex array object bound

Tags: macos, opengl, opengl-3, macos-mojave, vao

The following code **compiles and runs without errors on linux** but gives error

> "Error validating program: 'Validation Failed: No vertex array object bound."

on mac OS 10.14.2 (Mojave). Note that the program compiles successfully but has a problem during runtime.

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)

I am compiling using `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -w -framework OpenGL -lglfw -lGLEW -o p`

test.cpp

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;

#define cout(a) cout<<a<<endl

// IDs
GLuint VAO, VBO, VAO2, VBO2, shaderID, uniformModel;
float scale = 1.0, x = 0.0, y = 0.0;
const int numPoints = 50000;
const char* vShader = "shader.vert";
const char* fShader = "shader.frag";

void createSierpinskiGasket()
{
    GLfloat points[3 * numPoints];
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    points[0] = 0.25f; points[1] = 0.50f; points[2] = 0.0f;

    for(int i = 3; i < numPoints * 3; i += 3)
    {
        int j = rand() % 3;
        points[i] = (points[i - 3] + vertices[j * 3]) / 2.0;
        points[i + 1] = (points[i - 2] + vertices[j * 3 + 1]) / 2.0;
        points[i + 2] = (points[i - 1] + vertices[j * 3 + 2]) / 2.0;
    }

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO2);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO2);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void createTriangle()
{
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    // Subsequent code will be associated with this VAO
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    // GL_ARRAY_BUFFER = Vertex data
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    // GL_STATIC_DRAW = Not going to change the data (transforms are OK)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Location, number, type, normalize, stride, offset
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    // Enable location 0
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // Unbinding
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void addShader(const char* shaderIDCode, GLenum shaderIDType)
{
    GLuint theShader = glCreateShader(shaderIDType);

    const GLchar* theCode[1];
    theCode[0] = shaderIDCode;

    GLint codeLength[1];
    codeLength[0] = strlen(shaderIDCode);

    glShaderSource(theShader, 1, theCode, codeLength);
    glCompileShader(theShader);

    GLint result = 0;
    GLchar eLog[1024] = { 0 };

    glGetShaderiv(theShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(theShader, sizeof(eLog), NULL, eLog);
        printf("Error compiling the %d shaderID: '%s'\n", shaderIDType, eLog);
        return;
    }

    glAttachShader(shaderID, theShader);
}

void compileShader(const char* vertexCode, const char* fragmentCode)
{
    // Creating shaderID program
    shaderID = glCreateProgram();

    if(!shaderID)
    {
        cout("Error creating shaderID.");
        return;
    }

    addShader(vertexCode, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    addShader(fragmentCode, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    GLint result = 0;
    GLchar eLog[1024] = { 0 };

    glLinkProgram(shaderID);
    glGetProgramiv(shaderID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result)
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderID, sizeof(eLog), NULL, eLog);
        printf("Error linking program: '%s'\n", eLog);
        return;
    }

    glValidateProgram(shaderID);
    glGetProgramiv(shaderID, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result)
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderID, sizeof(eLog), NULL, eLog);
        printf("Error validating program: '%s'\n", eLog);
        return;
    }

}

string readFile(const char* fileLocation)
{
    string content;
    ifstream fileStream(fileLocation, ios::in);

    if (!fileStream.is_open()) {
        printf("Failed to read %s! File doesn't exist.", fileLocation);
        return "";
    }

    string line = "";
    while (!fileStream.eof())
    {
        getline(fileStream, line);
        content.append(line + "\n");
    }

    fileStream.close();
    return content;
}

void createShader(const char* vertexLocation, const char* fragmentLocation)
{
    string vertexString = readFile(vertexLocation);
    string fragmentString = readFile(fragmentLocation);
    const char* vertexCode = vertexString.c_str();
    const char* fragmentCode = fragmentString.c_str();

    compileShader(vertexCode, fragmentCode);
}

void handleKeys(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int code, int action, int mode)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    }

    if (key == GLFW_KEY_EQUAL && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        scale += 0.05;
    }

    if (key == GLFW_KEY_MINUS && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        scale -= 0.05;
    }

    if (key == GLFW_KEY_LEFT && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        x -= 0.05;
    }

    if (key == GLFW_KEY_RIGHT && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        x += 0.05;
    }

    if (key == GLFW_KEY_UP && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        y += 0.05;
    }

    if (key == GLFW_KEY_DOWN && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        y -= 0.05;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    const GLint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

    // Initializing GLFW
    if(!glfwInit())
    {
        cout("GLFW initialization failed.");
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup GLFW window properties
    // OpenGL version
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    // Not backwards compatible
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    // Allow forward compatibility
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow* mainWindow = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Test Window", NULL, NULL);
    if(!mainWindow)
    {
        cout("GLFW window creation failed.");
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Get buffer size information
    int bufferWidth, bufferHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(mainWindow, &bufferWidth, &bufferHeight);

    // Set context for GLEW to use
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(mainWindow);

    // Allow modern extension features
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        cout("GLEW initialization failed.");
        glfwDestroyWindow(mainWindow);
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup viewport size
    glViewport(0, 0, bufferWidth, bufferHeight);

    createTriangle();
    createShader(vShader, fShader);
    createSierpinskiGasket();

    uniformModel = glGetUniformLocation(shaderID, "model");

    // Loop until window is closed
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(mainWindow))
    {
        // Get and handle user input
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSetKeyCallback(mainWindow, handleKeys);

        // Clear window
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        // Clear colour buffer before next frame
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shaderID);

        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4();
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(x, y, 0));
        //model = glm::rotate(model, rotX * toRadians, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
        //model = glm::rotate(model, rotY * toRadians, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
        //model = glm::rotate(model, rotZ * toRadians, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(scale, scale, scale));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformModel, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        /*glBindVertexArray(VAO2);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, numPoints);
        glBindVertexArray(0);*/

        glUseProgram(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(mainWindow);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

shader.frag

```
#version 330

in vec4 vCol;

uniform mat4 model;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    //color = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    color = vec4(vCol.x, vCol.y, 0.5, 1.0);
}
```

shader.vert

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;

uniform mat4 model;

out vec4 vCol;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = model * vec4(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, 1.0f);
    vCol = vec4(clamp(pos, 0.0f, 1.0f), 1.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message

> Validation Failed: No vertex array object bound.

means that the validation of the program could not be performed, because no Vertex Array Object is bound, when [`glValidateProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glValidateProgram.xhtml) is called

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 11.1. VERTEX SHADERS; page 402](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)

> [...] As a development aid, use the command
>
> ```
> void ValidateProgram( uint program );
> ```
>
> **to validate the program object program against the current GL state**.

This means that the VAO which is should be drawn, by the shader program, has to be bound, before `glValidateProgram` is called.

Bind the "triangle" VAO, before the shader program is validated:

```
createTriangle();

glBindVertexArray(VAO);
createShader(vShader, fShader);
```